# Prove that $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0, \pi)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-continuity

I'm trying to solve the problem 2.d. in Manfred Stoll's "Introduction to Real Analysis", Exercises 4.3

It asks to show that $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0, \pi)$

I need to find 2 sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ s.t. $|x_n - y_n| \rightarrow 0$ but $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| \geq \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a positive number, but I and strugling with finding such sequences.

Is there any hint for finding such sequences?

Comment: what does f(x) do if x goes to zero?

Comment: Almost anything you try will work. For example, $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$, $y_n = \frac{2}{n}$

Answer (score 1):

No need to find the sequences in every case. In the case of finite intervals if $f$ is continuous in the finite interval and has limits at the end points then $f$ is uniformly continuous. The converse is also true. In this case $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{\sin x}$ does not exist. Hence it is not uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x_n=\frac{1}n, y_n=\frac2n$, so we have $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$, but

$$|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=\left| \frac{1}{\sin\frac1n}-\frac{1}{\sin\frac2n}\right|=\frac{\sin\frac2n-\sin\frac1n}{\sin\frac2n\cdot\sin\frac1n}\ge\frac{\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}6\cdot\frac{8}{n^3}-\frac1n}{\frac2n\cdot\frac1n}=\frac{n}2-\frac{2}{3n}\to\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_0,x_1 \in Dom(f)$ where $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

We call a function uniformly continuous if there's an existing $\delta > 0$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$ if $$|x_0-x_1| < \delta \hspace{0,3cm} \text{then} \hspace{0,3cm}|f(x_0)-f(x_1)| < \epsilon.$$

That means we have a uniform $\delta$ what does not depend on the location in the domain and the range of values of our function in $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ is below a certain value ($\epsilon$)

Assume that $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,\pi)$

Then we have such a $\delta$ mentioned above.

If we have a given $\epsilon > 0$ we have to prove, that there is no such uniform $\delta$.

Assume we have found the $\delta$ so every

$$ x_0,x_1 \in(x- \delta,x+ \delta) \hspace{1cm}  |\frac{1}{\sin x_1}-\frac{1}{\sin x_0}| < \epsilon $$ should hold.

But as $x_0$ and $x_1$ aproaches $0$, $|\frac{1}{\sin x_1}-\frac{1}{\sin x_0}|$ can be infinitely large.

So we can pick $x'$ such that for every $x'_0,x'_1 \in (x'-\delta,x'+\delta)$

$$|\frac{1}{\sin x'_1}-\frac{1}{\sin x'_0}| > \epsilon$$

So that means for every given $\epsilon$ we can find such $x_0,x_1$ where $$|f(x_0)-f(x_1)| > \epsilon$$, so it can not be uniformly continuous.

Remark:

You can think about uniform continuity as we move the centre of a recetangle through the function which sides are paralell to the axes. The side paralell to $x$ has the length $2\delta$ and the other paralell to $y$ has the length $2\epsilon$. We call a function uniformly continuous if we can moove this rectangle through the function and the graph of the function always intersects the sides paralell to the $y$ axis.

Hope that helps!